# Multiple Clients support in C# server Applicaton

Tags: c#, client

My server Application in C# supports 700 Connections and also it performing bulk data transfer.If i increase the connections it affects the data transfer ..

I need suggestion to increase the client Connection  with better data transfer without affecting existing and for every new connections also.

Comment: Too vague to be able to provide any feedback on this, ahem.... question

Comment: How does it affect the transfer? memory load, no longer accepting connections, slow byte rate? You need to give more insight, maybe some striped down example of your server code that is accepting connections

Comment: More memory utilization , Some times existing connections be affected

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft NLB can be used for creating active/active cluster. the issue seems to be of load balancing and scalibility.